# Google Authentification with Blazor Wasm STANDALONE

Tags: c#, google-oauth, webassembly

I have an Blazor web Assembly 'standalone' app that talk with a Rest Web API  and have implemented a local authentification that generate a JWT token and everything works great. I want to implement the possibility to use google external authentification. I saw several articles or video showing how to do it with a blazor webassembly ‘HOSTED’ but not with a standalone Wasm.  I understand that it seems that it must be done visa a web api but is it possible to have it done via a standard Rest api instead of a hosted wasm having an embeded mvc API?  I could Always migrate my whole app to a hoster wasm but it would be a lot of work as client and server are not the same domain.  I someone has ever done this or can direct me to how to proceed.